# Quartus Jungo WinDriver Installation on Fedora running 3.6 kernel

Tags: linux, fedora, intel-fpga, quartus

I have newly installed Quartus WebEdition 12 and I am trying to install device drivers.

`/opt/altera` is the folder where altera is installed.

`/opt/altera/quartus/drivers/wdrvr/linux64` is from where I am trying to install the drivers as advised by the professor.

The `configure` command executes well. It's `make` that fails saying that the kernel is too recent making it unsupported. I am on the 3.6.11 kernel on fedora.

Any help with issue?

Answer (score 1):

The error messages that you get simply means that pre-built kernel module that you are trying to load was built for the version of the Linux kernel that is not compatible with the version you are running. From here you have a few options:

1. Use one of the Linux distributions that are officially supported by Altera. For details, see [Operating System Support](http://www.altera.com/download/os-support/oss-index.html) page.
2. Build the Jungo driver from sources. This process usually uses the version of the kernel that you are currently running, and therefore should be totally compatible and stop complaining.

You probably want to go with the second option. Here is what Altera [has to say](http://www.altera.com/literature/ug/ug_cvp.pdf):

> **Installing the Jungo WinDriver Module in Linux Systems**
>
> Go to /quartus/drivers/wdrvr/linux[32|64]
>   and run these commands:
>
> ```
> $ ./configure--disable-usb-support b. make
> $ su
> $ make install
> ```
>
> Depending on how you wish to allow users to access the hardware
>   through the module, you can change the permissions for the device file
>   /dev/windrvr6 (for example, chmod 666 /dev/windrvr6).
>
> If you are running on a 64-bit Linux system, set the QUARTUS_64BIT
>   environment variable before running quartus_cvp using the following
>   command:
>
> ```
> export QUARTUS_64BIT=1
> ```

Before you do that, make sure you have kernel source code by running the following:

```
su -c 'yum install kernel-devel'
```

Hope it helps.  Good Luck!